# How to store typed infomation in a method from Scanner

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program and I am stuck at what I am sure is a very simple problem. In my code I want the user to type in a name and then have that name stored or used in the mutator method I have created. I can't get past the error on kb.nextLine

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CustomerDriver extends PreferredCustomer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    PreferredCustomer customer1 = new PreferredCustomer();

    System.out.println("Enter Customer Name: ");
    input = kb.nextLine(customer1.setName(name));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign `customer1`'s name from the result of the `nextLine` call, you need to do it like this:

```
customer1.setName(kb.nextLine());
```

You do not need an intermediate variable: the result of the `kb.nextLine()` call will be passed to the `setName` as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was a dumb mistake. Now I can do the same for the rest of the other variables.

Comment: @StevenEck Follow the same pattern: call the setter with the `sk.nextXYZ()` results. For example, if you store height as an int, you'd do `customer1.setHeight(kb.nextInt());`.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran into that actually. I have some doubles and ints in there and just started fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

Move `customer1.setName(name)` to the next line:

```
input = kb.nextLine();
customer1.setName(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
customer1.setName(kb.nextLine());
```